# PHP error Can't use method return > value in write context

Tags: php, class, constants, isset

I am getting this error in a PHP class...

> Fatal error: Can't use method return
>   value in write context in
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\includes\classes\User.class.php
>   on line 35

Here is the troubled part.

```
if(isset($this->session->get('user_id')) && $this->session->get('user_id') != ''){
    //run code
}
```

This code is in my contrustor, is a value is not already set for $this->session->get('user_id') then it will return false instead of a Number.   So as you can see I was hoping to check if this value is a number or not or not even set.

Any help with fixing appreciated.

Comment: I've accustomed myself to returning null from method's that are expected to return values, when no value is present, and only return booleans (true/false) from methods that should return an indication of whether an operation failed/succeeded. You might want to concider using this paradigm too. The benifit is that, especially when a method is expected to return a number, you won't mistake the value zero for false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use **isset** for the result of a function. Consider the following code instead:

```
if( $this->session->get('user_id') ){
    //run code
}
```

Comment: Remember that if your application allows for a user_id with the value 0, this will fail, as 0 evaluates to false. A user_id of 0 might be unlikely in many applications, but still wanted to point it out.

Comment: Hmmm, now that I read the OP's question more thoroughly, I see he mentioned the method returns false if there is no user_id. Still, maybe: if( false !== $this->session->get('user_id') ) ... might be a little more save.

Answer (score 13):

> isset() only works with variables as
>   passing anything else will result in a
>   parse error. For checking if constants
>   are set use the defined() function.

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `isset` on a function. However, since `false`, `0`, and `''` all equate to a falsey statement, write your test this way:

```
if( $id = $this->sessions->get('user_id') ){
   // Will only run if $id does not equal '', False, or 0
}
```

That way you have run your test *and* assigned the variable in one step.

Comment: A word of caution, regarding assignment in an if() -- it's easy to get a little confused if you add a second condition to your if.  The && operator takes precedence over assignment, so `if($id = myFunc() && $id > 0)` is logically equivalent to `if($id = (myFunc() && $id > 0))`, while what you probably mean is `if(($id = myFunc()) && $id > 0)`.  Just wanted to throw that out there, 'cause it's a minor error I find myself making now and then, and it can be difficult to catch if you don't know to look for it.